# GCC not linking against libstdc++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, linker-errors

I'm receiving C++ build errors on Ubuntu 16.04 (g++ 5.4) that I don't understand:

The linker errors are (taken a few of them and run them through `c++filt`)

```
undefined reference to symbol 'std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
undefined reference to symbol 'std::condition_variable::notify_one()@@GLIBCXX_3.4.11'
```

The command lanks I'm using are: `gcc  -std=c++11 -m64 -fPIC -std=c++11 ...` (the ... has all the libs, *etc.*)

I assume I'm trying to link against `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`.  When I run `strings` against it, I see `GLIBCXX_3.4` and `GLIBCXX_3.4.11` (but I really don't know what this is indicating.)

nm shows me that the symbols (at least the `condition_variable` one is defined)

```
$ nm -DA /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | c++filt | grep condition_variable::notify_one
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6:00000000000b3930 T std::condition_variable::notify_one()
```

I've run `readelf` on all the libraries I'm attempting to link, and they all appear to be built for the same ABI (`GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609`)

### Update

I noticed that the first error is resolved by explicitly linking against `libstd++.so` (*i.e.* I added `stdc++` to my `target_link_libraries` in CMake).  I was under the impression that I should never have to do this?

Comment: I've noticed similar issues on 14.04, I now suspect that it might be related to adding shared libraries into static library targets in CMake.  I'm unsure though because this only results in problems sometimes.

Comment: Try to link with G++ not LD.

Comment: I'm not actually sure how to do that?  The LD comes from gcc.  like, I type `gcc -std=c++11 -m64 -fpic -o ....`, and the output is from `ld`.  I did notice two libstdc++.so.6's on my computer, so I'm trying to figure out if the nvidia one `/usr/NV/lib/libstdc++.so.6` is somehow getting in my build path?

Comment: You need to use `g++`, not `gcc`

Comment: omg.. I can't believe I missed that.  I now see how it snuck in there too.  I'm an idiot.  k, thanks! =D

Comment: @SergeyA: Please post this as an answer which OP can accept.

Comment: @einpoklum will be hard to fill it with the minimum length :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr: Invoke `g++` rather than `gcc` to avoid this problem

<sub>(based on @SergeyA's comment)</sub>

GCC behaves differently depending on whether you run it as the `gcc` or the `g++` binary. Specifically, it apparently won't automatically link against its bundled C++ standard library, `libstdc++`. I'm guessing it will link against its C standard library - which doesn't help you much.

So just use the appropriate binary for your language; specifying `--std=c++whatever` isn't enough.